# How to save the output of constituency parsing diagram as an image?

Tags: python, nlp

Using the svgling module I have generated the constituency parse tree. Here is the github link of svgling: [svgling module github](https://github.com/rawlins/svgling)

```
pip install svgling
import svgling
import nltk
var ='(S (NP this tree) (VP (V is) (AdjP pretty)))'
svgling.disable_nltk_png()
random=svgling.draw_tree(nltk.Tree.fromstring(var))
display(random)
```

Using this code I have got the diagram as an output (given below) of the constituency parse tree. I want to generate .png file of this output.
[Constituency parse tree (Output of the above code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BJrG.png)

To save the output as .png file I have run this following code.

```
import os
from nltk.tree import Tree
from nltk.draw.tree import TreeView
from nltk.draw.util import CanvasFrame
from nltk.draw import TreeWidget
os.system('Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x16  &')    # create virtual display with size 1600x1200 and 16 bit color. Color can be changed to 24 or 8
os.environ['DISPLAY']=':1.0' 
t = Tree.fromstring('(S (NP this tree) (VP (V is) (AdjP pretty)))')
cf = CanvasFrame()
TreeView(t)._cframe.print_to_file('output.ps')
os.system('convert output.ps output.png')
```

However, this code is showing error in google colab `TclError: couldn't connect to display ":1.0"`  and returning a numerical value (ex: 4) in jupyter notebook.

I tried to look into it on several websites but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I also had to convert the constituency parsing diagram as an image.
To do so, at first I have converted it into PostScript (.ps) file. And, from .ps file converted it into .png file.

To convert the tree diagram into the .ps file I ran the following code. This will give output.ps file.

```
from nltk.tree import Tree
from nltk.draw.tree import TreeView
t = Tree.fromstring('(S (NP this tree) (VP (V is) (AdjP pretty)))')
TreeView(t)._cframe.print_to_file('output.ps')
```

However, I was trying to run the code on google colab. And it was giving the error:

> TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable in
> Google Colab

To resolve the issue, ran the following code:

```
!apt-get install -y xvfb # Install X Virtual Frame Buffer
import os
os.system('Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x16  &')    # create virtual display with size 1600x1200 and 16 bit color. Color can be changed to 24 or 8
os.environ['DISPLAY']=':1.0'
```

Now to convert output.ps file into output.png:

```
!apt install ghostscript python3-tk
from PIL import Image
psimage=Image.open('output.ps')
psimage.save('output.png')
```

However, could not manage to get very good image quality in this way.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to export an svg to a raster image, my preferred way to do so in python by far is by using the [`cairosvg`](https://cairosvg.org/) package -- it's much easier than any of the ps-based paths discussed here.

Since this question has been asked, svgling (in ver 0.4.0) added direct support for this conversion path as long as `cairosvg` is installed -- see [the svgling manual for more details](https://rawlins.github.io/svgling/manual.html#svgling-compatibility-and-conversion). In a nutshell, adapting the original example, you can run something like:

```
import nltk, svgling, svgling.utils
t = svgling.draw_tree(nltk.Tree.fromstring('(S (NP this tree) (VP (V is) (AdjP pretty)))'))
# will error without cairosvg installed. Uses a high scale to compensate
# for the vector -> raster conversion.
svgling.utils.svg2png(t, scale=2.0, write_to="tree.png")
```